# First setTimeout works but others doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wrote this code

```
bot.on('message', message=>
{
    if(message.content === "come here")
    {
        message.channel.send('hey');
        setTimeout(() => {  message.channel.send('i am here'); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {  message.channel.send('and i hope you are fine'); }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {  message.channel.send('what do you want me to do?'); }, 1000);
    }
})
```

First setTimeout works perfectly. When it sends "hey", it waits 1 second before send "i'm here" but it doesn't wait before send other 2 sentences. Where is my mistake?

Comment: you realize they all will fire at one second? There is no delay between each of them.

Comment: `'i'm here'` syntax error

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your answers. i fixed the line increased delay for each one of them

Comment: the problem is that this is not how callbacks work, all of this code runs to the end of the file immediately and in order, then 3 callbacks are placed onto the event loop to wait 1 second before they console log. In this case it means all 3 messages will fire simultaneously after 1 seconds instead of sequentially for 1 second three times. This is a fundamental concept of callbacks and async/sync behaviour in general. I suggest looking here https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-asynchronous-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function in `setTimeout` would execute after a delay, which in in your case is 1 second for all three statements.
To space them apart by 1 second:

```
setTimeout(() => {  message.channel.send('i\'m here'); }, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {  message.channel.send('and i hope you are fine'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {  message.channel.send('what do you want me to do?'); }, 3000);
```